# Avoiding Template operator overload collisions for float and non float on the operator first argument

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if, redefinition

I have a situation where my template modulus operator does play nice between floats and integer-ish types.
As I recall there is a way to make it select the more specific one over the broader scope one, but i can't seem to find or remember how to do this.

Basically I have 2 methods which are coliding (redefinition error.)

What I am trying to do is get the specialized modulus operator overload to be used when its the type (T_COORDS) is float, the the broader one when it's not float.

The specialized one (notice it uses the math fmod function):

```
template <size_t N
    , enable_if_t<N != 0 && N <= C_COORDS*N_COORDS && N % C_COORDS == 0, bool> = false>
friend Coords operator % (const Coords<float,C_COORDS,N_COORDS>& coords0, const auto (& coords1)[N])
{
  Coords<float,C_COORDS,N_COORDS> result = coords0;
  for (int i=0; i < C_COORDS*N_COORDS; i++)
      result.coords[i] = fmod(result.coords[i], coords1[i%N]);
  return result;
}
```

The broader one (notice it uses the standard float modulus):

```
template <std::size_t N
    , std::enable_if_t<N != 0 && N <= C_COORDS*N_COORDS && N % C_COORDS == 0
    , bool> = false>
friend Coords operator % (const Coords<T_COORDS,C_COORDS,N_COORDS>& coords0, const auto (& coords1)[N])
{
  Coords<T_COORDS,C_COORDS,N_COORDS> result = coords0;
  for (int i=0; i < C_COORDS*N_COORDS; i++)
      result.coords[i] %= coords1[i%N];
  return result;
}
```

Those overloads are enclosed with a Template class definition:

```
template <class T_COORDS, size_t C_COORDS, size_t N_COORDS>
class Coords {
public:

  T_COORDS coords[C_COORDS*N_COORDS];

  // (body in here)

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T_COORDS` is a class template parameter, not a function template parameter, which means it makes no difference for partial ordering as the more general function is instantiated with `T_COORDS=float` anyway, and so it's exactly the same as the `float` one. You can, however, disable that function from overload resolution, utilizing the fact that it already has some `enable_if` conditions that are dependent on immediate context:

```
template <std::size_t N
        , std::enable_if_t<N != 0 && N <= C_COORDS*N_COORDS && N % C_COORDS == 0
                           && !std::is_same<T_COORDS, float>{}
                           // ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        , bool> = false>
friend Coords operator %(const Coords<T_COORDS, C_COORDS, N_COORDS>& coords0
                       , const auto (& coords1)[N]);
```

Comment: Well  that works.  Thank you.  I'm just wondering about doubles now.  I think I may be going about this the wrong way.   For now I am using your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your logic but if you want to make your function behavior change upon the type double or not, you can use something like the following..

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
void func(){
    constexpr static bool isFloat = std::is_floating_point<T>::value;//static in classes
    if (isFloat) std::cout << "f\n";//u can use fmod() here
    else std::cout << "i\n";//use regular % here
}
int main(){
    func<int>();
    func<double>();
}
```

Comment: That's very good and handles both floats and doubles.  Thank you.  But i'd rather it simply used the method overload that is most suited for the inner class (T_COORDS) then do conditional execution, that is if I understand this correct.   I think the best thing to do is study up on template so I have a better understanding of how to use them.

Comment: Yeah, I removed a bunch of code to post because I thought it would help focus, but I see it only causes mystery..  Thanks for the feedback, I will be posting more complete examples / code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep just one of those overloads but change its for loop to this:

```
for (int i=0; i < C_COORDS*N_COORDS; i++)
    result.coords[i] = my_mod(result.coords[i], coords1[i%N]);
```

After defining my_mod like this (in the outer scope):

```
template <typename T>
T my_mod(const T& x, const T& y) { return x % y; }

float my_mod(float x, float y) { return fmod(x, y); }
// maybe define it for double as well
```